# Can I create an object with multiple options in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I a have an HTML table with 10+ rows. First cell of each row requires the user to select an option from a dropdown list. What I am trying to do is to first define an object like:

```
define myobject [id=?] {
<select id="cars" name="?">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

and then use this object in each of my table rows, something like:

```
<form action="includes/process.php" method="post">
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>myobject[id=obj1]</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>myobject[id=obj2]</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
  <td>myobject[id=obj3]</td>
 </tr>
</table>
<button type="submit" name="process-submit">Process</button>

</form>
```

So that when I submit my form, obj1, obj2 and obj3 show up as different values in the POST var.

Apologies in advance if the question is too vague or confusing. Is this doable? How?

Comment: Yes it is definitely doable, you will need to write the code to do it. You can't ask for other to do it for you.

Comment: @AdrianBrand Thanks!!! I was not sure OOP is possible in HTML. I still am not.

Comment: Where is the form?

Comment: @hev1 Edited the code. Table appears within the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` to get all the table rows elements in the `form`, add select elements to each of the first cells, add change event listeners to all of them to update the `textContent` of the adjacent table cell.

Demo:

```js
const trs = document.querySelectorAll("form tr");
trs.forEach((tr,idx) => {
    const firstCell = tr.querySelector('td');
  firstCell.innerHTML = `<select id="cars${idx+1}" name="cars${idx+1}">
       <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
       <option value="saab">Saab</option>
       <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
       <option value="audi">Audi</option>
     </select>`;
    const secondCell = firstCell.nextElementSibling;
    const select = firstCell.querySelector('select');
    secondCell.textContent = select.value;
    select.addEventListener('change', function(e){
        secondCell.textContent = select.value;
    });
});
```

```html
<form action="includes/process.php" method="post">
<table>
 <tr>
   <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<button type="submit" name="process-submit">Process</button>
</form>
```

Comment: actually I am trying to find a way to shrink my code. Instead of using ```      <select id="cars" name="cars">
       <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
       <option value="saab">Saab</option>
       <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
       <option value="audi">Audi</option>
     </select>``` I want to define a custom tag, say <mytag></mytag> that can replace this code.

Comment: @user3750702 Instead of using what?

Comment: If you make a custom tag, you will still have to specify options, which would not reduce the code size by much and also renders it more inflexible.

Comment: I want to keep the options same for all the tags in one column. With 10+ rows, a single tag will help. And will go a long way for a table with 60-70 cells. I guess I will use php functions to do the job for now.

Comment: @user3750702 I have updated my answer for that case.

Comment: Thanks a ton. That's awesome.

Comment: @user3750702 No problem.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that once you have created the object then you save the options in an array:

```
function Options(options) {
    this.options = options;
}


var options: [option1, option2, option3 ]
```

then create a constructor and pass this array to that constructor.

```
 myobject.prototype.displayOptions = function() {

    console.log(this.options); 

    for (var i = 0; i < this.options.length; i++) {
        console.log(i + ': ' + this.options[i]);
    }
}

options.displayOptions();
```

Answer (score 1):

After you've created the `<select>` object, you can use clone it and append where you want it, and repeat.
For more information, look here: [Node.cloneNode() - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)
and here: [HTML DOM cloneNode Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_clonenode.asp)